# Can't enter values in input fields reactjs

Tags: reactjs, firebase

I am doing a login and registration form with reactjs and firebase.

I created the fields properly but I cannot enter values in the input fields I created(email,password) to save in my firebase project. I don't know what the problems is. Everything seems okay for me. I need help. When I remove `val.email` in the email fields value, I can enter values in the field but I won't be able to save the data which was entered in the fields in the database. It is the same situation iIam facing with password, I don't kow what I am missing. I'll be waiting for a good response.

```
import React from "react";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import Footer from "../components/Footers/Footer";
import Navbar from "./Navbars/AuthNavbar";
import firebase from 'firebase';
import app from '../utils/firebase';

const Login=() =>{
const [val, setVal] = React.useState({
email: '',
password: '',});
const handleChange = (e) => {const value = e.target.value;const name = 
e.target.name;setVal((prevState) => ({ ...prevState, [name]: value }));};
const handleLoginButton = () => {
setLoader({ googleLoading: false, buttonLoading: true });
if(!val.email || !val.password){
  setError({ message: 'Email and Password are required', open: true });
  setLoader({ googleLoading: false, buttonLoading: false });
}else {
  setError({message:'', open: false });
  app.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(val.email, val.password).then((user) => {
      console.log(user)
      setLoader({ googleLoading: false, buttonLoading: false })
  }).catch(error => {
      console.log(error, 'error in loggin in');
      setError({ message: error.message, open: true });
      setLoader({ googleLoading: false, buttonLoading: false });
  })
}
};
<div className="flex-auto px-4 lg:px-10 py-10 pt-0">
            <div className="text-blueGray-400 text-center mb-3 font-bold">
              <small>Or sign in with credentials</small>
            </div>
            <form>
              <div className="relative w-full mb-3">
                <label
                  className="block uppercase text-blueGray-600 text-xs font-bold mb-2"
                  htmlFor="grid-password"
                >
                  Email
                </label>
                <input
                  type="email"
                  value={val.email}
                  onChange={handleChange}
                  className="border-0 px-3 py-3 placeholder-blueGray-300 text-blueGray-600 bg-white rounded text-sm shadow focus:outline-none focus:ring w-full ease-linear transition-all duration-150"
                  placeholder="Email"
                />
              </div>

              <div className="relative w-full mb-3">
                <label
                  className="block uppercase text-blueGray-600 text-xs font-bold mb-2"
                  htmlFor="grid-password"
                >
                  Password
                </label>
                <input
                value={val.password}
                onChange={handleChange}
                  type="password"
                  className="border-0 px-3 py-3 placeholder-blueGray-300 text-blueGray-600 bg-white rounded text-sm shadow focus:outline-none focus:ring w-full ease-linear transition-all duration-150"
                  placeholder="Password"
                />
              </div>
              <div>
                <label className="inline-flex items-center cursor-pointer">
                  <input
                    id="customCheckLogin"
                    type="checkbox"
                    className="form-checkbox border-0 rounded text-blueGray-700 ml-1 w-5 h-5 ease-linear transition-all duration-150"
                  />
                  <span className="ml-2 text-sm font-semibold text-blueGray-600">
                    Remember me
                  </span>
                </label>
              </div>
             
              <div className="text-center mt-6">
                <button
                  onClick={() => handleLoginButton()}
                  className="bg-blue-800 text-white active:bg-blueGray-600 text-sm font-bold uppercase px-6 py-3 rounded shadow hover:shadow-lg outline-none focus:outline-none mr-1 mb-1 w-full ease-linear transition-all duration-150"
                  type="button"
                >
                  Sign In
                </button>
              </div>
```

Comment: Please try to indent your code, as this is not easily readable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing **name** property in your input fields. That's why your state was not updating and you were getting nothing in value of property.

This will help you

```js
import React from "react";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import Footer from "../components/Footers/Footer";
import Navbar from "./Navbars/AuthNavbar";
import firebase from 'firebase';
import app from '../utils/firebase';

const Login=() =>{
const [val, setVal] = React.useState({
email: '',
password: ''
});

const handleChange = (e) => {const value = e.target.value;const name = 
e.target.name;setVal((prevState) => ({ ...prevState, [name]: value }));};
const handleLoginButton = () => {
   setLoader({ googleLoading: false, buttonLoading: true });

if(!val.email || !val.password){
  setError({ message: 'Email and Password are required', open: true });
  setLoader({ googleLoading: false, buttonLoading: false });
}else {
  setError({message:'', open: false });
  app.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(val.email, 
  val.password).then((user) => {
      console.log(user)
      setLoader({ googleLoading: false, buttonLoading: false })
  }).catch(error => {
      console.log(error, 'error in loggin in');
      setError({ message: error.message, open: true });
      setLoader({ googleLoading: false, buttonLoading: false });
  })
}
};
<div className="flex-auto px-4 lg:px-10 py-10 pt-0">
            <div className="text-blueGray-400 text-center mb-3 font-bold">
              <small>Or sign in with credentials</small>
            </div>
            <form>
              <div className="relative w-full mb-3">
                <label
                  className="block uppercase text-blueGray-600 text-                    xs font-bold mb-2"
                  htmlFor="grid-password"
                >
                  Email
                </label>
                <input
                name="email"
                  type="email"
                  value={val.email}
                  onChange={handleChange}
                  className="border-0 px-3 py-3 placeholder-blueGray-300 text-blueGray-600 bg-white rounded text-sm shadow focus:outline-none focus:ring w-full ease-linear transition-all duration-150"
                  placeholder="Email"
                />
              </div>

              <div className="relative w-full mb-3">
                <label
                  className="block uppercase text-blueGray-600 text-                            xs font-bold mb-2"
                  htmlFor="grid-password"
                >
                  Password
                </label>
                <input
                name="password"
                value={val.password}
                onChange={handleChange}
                  type="password"
                  className="border-0 px-3 py-3 placeholder-blueGray-300 text-blueGray-600 bg-white rounded text-sm shadow focus:outline-none focus:ring w-full ease-linear transition-all duration-150"
                  placeholder="Password"
                />
              </div>
              <div>
                <label className="inline-flex items-center cursor-pointer">
                  <input
                    id="customCheckLogin"
                    type="checkbox"
                    className="form-checkbox border-0 rounded text-blueGray-700 ml-1 w-5 h-5 ease-linear transition-all duration-150"
                  />
                  <span className="ml-2 text-sm font-semibold text-blueGray-600">
                    Remember me
                  </span>
                </label>
              </div>
             
              <div className="text-center mt-6">
                <button
                  onClick={() => handleLoginButton()}
                  className="bg-blue-800 text-white active:bg-blueGray-600 text-sm font-bold uppercase px-6 py-3 rounded shadow hover:shadow-lg outline-none focus:outline-none mr-1 mb-1 w-full ease-linear transition-all duration-150"
                  type="button"
                >
                  Sign In
                </button>
              </div>
```

Comment: Thanks so much dude, that was what i was missing. it solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your handleLoginButton is missing the preventDefault method. Since your input field tags and button are inside the form tag, whenever your button is clicked, it will reload the window. By calling preventDefault you stop the window from reloading and trying to submit the form to the localhost server.

```
const handleLoginButton = (event) => {
   event.preventDefault()
...
}
```

update button onClick

```
onClick={handleLoginButton}
```

or

```
onClick={(e) => handleLoginButton(e)}
```

You also need to set name property on your input tag.
See documentation: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input

Your handleChange is trying to access the 'name' with e.target.name, however that hasn't been set on the input. See below.

```
<input
                  type="email"
                  name="email"
                  value={val.email}
                  onChange={handleChange}
                  placeholder="Email"
                />
```

Comment: Thanks, i tried that but i cant still enter values in the fields

Comment: Oh, yeah, you need to set name prop on your inputs.

Comment: the problem is not at the level of the button but at the input fields(email,password). I can't enter any values in those fields

Comment: how should i go about it?

Comment: Sounds great. If this was the right answer please upvote and mark it.